# Rich function on Flink join, Scala API

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I'm struggling with Flink and Scala.

I have a join transformation over a `DataSet` that pretty much works, but I want to turn it into a `RichFuntion`, so that I can access a broadcasted set:

```
val newBoard: DataSet[Cell] = board.rightOuterJoin(neighbours)
                             .where("coords").equalTo("cellCoords"){

    (cell, neighbours) => {
            // Do some rich function things, like 
            // override the open method so I can get
            // the broadcasted set
    }

  }

}.withBroadcastSet(board, "aliveCells")
```

I have been looking all over the documentation, but I can't find any example of a `RichJoinFuntion` being used in Scala. I only find [examples](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/apis/batch/index.html#broadcast-variables) for rich functions used in `map` or `filter`, but the syntax is different for the `join` transformation (function between parenthesis vs. between brackets).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `RichJoinFunction` with the Scala DataSet API as follows

```
val newBoard: DataSet[Cell] = board.rightOuterJoin(neighbours)
                             .where("coords").equalTo("cellCoords")
                               .apply(new YourJoinFunction())
                               .withBroadcastSet(board, "aliveCells")

class YourJoinFunction extends RichJoinFunction[IN1, IN2, Cell] {
  override def join(first: IN1, second: IN2): Cell = {
    // Do some rich function things, like 
    // override the open method so I can get
    // the broadcasted set
  }
}
```